# Symfony autowire - What is the relationship between different service.yml files?

Tags: symfony, autowired

I am working on migrating an existing `Symfony 2.8` project to `Symfony 3.4`. In this process I would like to use `autowire` to automatically configure/setup services.

Coming from SF 2 my project is still organized in different bundles and thus I use different `services.yml` files.

It seems that the settings from the projects `services.yml` are not (completely) applied to the bundle specific `services.yml` files. **I wonder if this is expected or if there is something wrong with my config.**

**The concrete problem:**

```
// app/config/config.yml
imports:
    - { resource: "@AppBundle/Resources/config/services.yml" }
    ...


// app/config/services.yml
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true
        public: false
        bind:
            $debug: '%kernel.debug%'


// src/AppBundle/Resources/config/services.yml
services:
    AppBundle\Controller\CustomExceptionController:
        public: true
        #autowire: true
        #arguments:
        #    $debug: '%kernel.debug%'


// AppBundle\Controller\CustomExceptionController
class CustomExceptionController extends ExceptionController {
    public function __construct(\Twig_Environment $twig, $debug) {
        parent::__construct($twig, $debug);
        ....
    }
}
```

The `CustomExceptionController` only works when the service is defined as `public`. Since the `_defaults` are set to create `private` services this as to be defined manually. Since the controller belongs to the `AppBundle` I would (for now) like to keep this config in the the bundles `service.yml`

However, only applying `public: true` does **NOT work**:

> Type error: Too few arguments to function
>   AppBundle\Controller\CustomExceptionController::__construct(), 0
>   passed in
>   .../project/var/cache/dev/ContainerW0i3edc/getCustomExceptionControllerService.php
>   on line 11 and exactly 2 expected

Although the message mentions the cache, this is not a caching problem (deleting the folders and re-building the cache does not change anything).

Only if I add `autowire: true` to the concrete service definition, autowire tries to setup the service. However, I still get the following message:

> Cannot autowire service
>   "AppBundle\Controller\CustomExceptionController": argument "$debug"
>   of method "__construct()" has no type-hint, you should configure its
>   value explicitly.

**Since the `$debug` is bound in the `app/config/services.yml` this souldn't be a problem, should it?** However, it only works if I explitly set the argument in the `src/AppBundle/Resources/config/services.yml`.

**Why is `autowire: true` not applied to the services defined in the bundle `services.yml`?**

**Why is the binding from the project `services.yml` not applied to the services defined in the bundle `services.yml`?**

**Is the expected behavior or is there something wrong with my config?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is autowire: true not applied to the services defined in the bundle services.yml?
>
> Why is the binding from the project services.yml not applied to the services defined in the bundle services.yml?
>
> Is the expected behavior or is there something wrong with my config?

To all your questions:

`_defaults` is applied **only to locally defined services, not imported ones**.
That's because such global application could break external configs.

#### How to Solve Your Problem?

Add `_defaults` section to `src/AppBundle/Resources/config/services.yml` file.

You can read more about Symfony 3.3+ DI changes [in documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/service_container/3.3-di-changes.html) or in my [post with *before/after* examples](https://www.tomasvotruba.cz/blog/2017/05/07/how-to-refactor-to-new-dependency-injection-features-in-symfony-3-3/).